# WallpaperEngine.onOffsetsChanged not being called using a HTC Sensation

Tags: android

WallpaperEngine.onOffsetsChanged not being called using a HTC Sensation, but it is ok with my other two devices (Nexus 7, and a Nexus S).

I understand that this issue is related to the HTC Sense 3 carousel.

I have downloaded a number of Live wallpapers to test them out on the device and quite a lot of them don't pan between home screens.. But some do, so there MUST be a workaround for this bug/restriction.

Anyone know what it is?